# Running RSE java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nachos

I'm currently taking an OS course in which we are using [Nachos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System) as a learning platform.  It is written in Java and located on a remote server that I SSH into.  I would like to use Eclipse on my local machine to debug this project, and so I set it up using the RSE plugin.

I can view/edit all of the files successfully, however I'm having trouble getting it to run.  I set up a run configuration, using the working directory as a workspace `${workspace_loc:_remoteHost_ _nachos/proj0}` where *remoteHost* is the name of the host server.  This filepath was generated when I used the explorer to search for a workspace.

When I click *Run*, it says:

```
'Launching proj0' has encountered a problem.

Variable references non-existent resource:
${workspace_loc:remoteHost_nachos/proj0}
```

Now, I know that the resource does exist so I'm not sure why this is happening.  I followed some instructions to get this set up, but they were intended for a locally stored project.  I'm guessing this happening because its a remote project?  Am I doing this wrong?  I'm not too well versed with Eclipse, so I must be missing something here.